# Lt s-> 0 Arctan (s/m) for m>0 and m<0 ?

Tags: limits

For m>0 it should be 0. But what about m<0 as in that case value of Arctan s/m will move from 0+ to 0- as s will move from 0- to 0+.

Answer (score 2):

$\arctan(x)=x-x^3/3+x^5/5+\cdots$ thus $m>0$ or $m<0$ no matter $\lim_{s\to 0} \arctan \frac{s}{m}=0$